# Pesquisa percorrer por quatro colunas na tabela com LambdaExpressions

Tags: c#, api, expressões-lambda

Olá, estou fazendo um sistema de pesquisas e tenho o seguinte caso: o usuário vai digitar uma data no input, e tenho quatro colunas de data no banco de dados(data1, data2, data3, data4), queria fazer com que essa data digitada, percorresse por todos esses quatro campos e caso pelo menos uma dessas datas seja igual a digitada, retornaria no resultado.

Tenho feito apenas para a primeira data, pois não consegui fazer para as outras em questão.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
{
     var result = await _context.Usuarios
         .Where(r => r.data1.Contains(data))
         .ToListAsync();
     return result;
 }
```

O retorno seria basicamente todas as informações do usuário, porém apenas usuários com a data igual a que foi digitada anteriormente.

Comment: se o campo for do tipo "data" (`DATE` ou `DATETIME` por exemplo), deveria comparar assim se tiver a data exata: `Where (r => r.data1 == data) `, mas de qualquer forma pode usar o operador "OU": `.Where(r => (r.data1.Contains(data) || (r.data2.Contains(data) ....)` e compara com quantos campos quiser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função Any() do LINQ para percorrer todas as quatro colunas de data no banco de dados e verificar se pelo menos uma delas é igual à data digitada pelo usuário. Aqui está um exemplo de como você pode fazer isso:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
{
    var result = await _context.Usuarios
        .Where(r => r.data1.Contains(data) || r.data2.Contains(data) || r.data3.Contains(data) || r.data4.Contains(data))
        .ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Nesse exemplo, estamos usando o operador || (ou) para verificar se a data digitada pelo usuário é igual a pelo menos uma das quatro colunas de data no banco de dados. Você pode encadear quantas condições || forem necessárias para cobrir todas as colunas que você deseja verificar.

Caso você queira uma comparação exata de datas em vez de usar Contains(), você pode usar == ou Equals() para comparar as datas diretamente, dependendo do tipo de dados que você está usando no banco de dados. Por exemplo:

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
{
    var result = await _context.Usuarios
        .Where(r => r.data1 == data || r.data2 == data || r.data3 == data || r.data4 == data)
        .ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Lembrando que essa comparação exata de datas pode variar dependendo do formato de data que você está usando no banco de dados e do formato de data que o usuário está digitando. Certifique-se de estar comparando as datas de forma correta para obter os resultados esperados.